# error registering dll in server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, 64-bit, dll

I am trying to register a 32 bit com.dll in sysWOW64

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 xxx.dll i have copied the dll in both the
>   folders SysWOW64 and System32

it shows error like

> The module "xxx.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at
>   the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary
>   or dependent .DLL files

if i check dependency walker there it shows some missing files what are these files?

> ATL110.DLL, MSVCR110.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL, MFPLAT.DLL, WLANAPI.DLL

these files are really necessary? i have downloaded redist files to overcome the problem but it failed still it shows the same error after installing the redist files

i have installed the same dll in **windows 7 x64** and it registered successfully system but not in **windows 2012 server x64** what cause the error? how to resolve the problem

Comment: Is this a Server Core installation, or one with the full desktop GUI?

Comment: server core installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to register a DLL on a Windows Server Core installation, but that DLL expects the components of the full desktop GUI to be present.

The giveaway for me (and why I asked you which version it was), is because I recognize some of those DLL names from a former life. For example:

- IESHIMS.dll is a DLL that is used for proxying certain calls to Internet Explorer, but Server Core does not have Internet Explorer

Basically your DLL is incompatible with Windows Core. Even if you were able to make those DLLs available, chances are it still would not work, because those DLLs in turn will rely on other features that are not available.